# Sorting deep dictionary [Python]

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have a program that takes 3 keys and values per project for 5 different environments and makes a JSON file out of it. It looks like this (simplified).

Note : the number of project can change and they can't have the same name inside different environments, they have a tag at the end of them.

Note 2 : The project name aren't "project1" "project2", they follow a specific naming scheme making them unique.

```
{
    "env_preprod": {
        "project1": {
            "consumption last month": 127.283851, 
            "quotas": 200, 
            "consumption ": 117.657964
        }, 
        "project2": {
            "consumption last month": 0.000891, 
            "quotas": 200, 
            "consumption ": 0.00018
        }
    }
    "env_prod": {
        "project1": {
            "consumption last month": 127.283851, 
            "quotas": 200, 
            "consumption ": 117.657964
        }, 
        "project2": {
            "consumption last month": 0.000891, 
            "quotas": 200, 
            "consumption ": 0.00018
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have the projects in the 5 different behing sorted by consumption but couldn't get it done.
I tried to use the lambda function as such :

```
sort = dict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['consumption']))
```

I also tried this but I didn't sort values:

```
res = {key : dict(sorted(val.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1]))
       for key, val in data.items()}
```

I think at this point only a loop would do it but can't figure it out properly right now. I just need to sort the projects inside envs by ascending values of consumption. Got any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: Which python are you using? 2.7 or 3?

Comment: Using 2.7 as dev env but the real use will be in 3.8

Comment: can't write a real answer right now but python2 dict are not keep order, try using OrderedDict (from collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your'e using Python2 try this:

```
{
    key: OrderedDict(
        sorted(value.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['consumption '])
    ) 
    for key, value in data.items()
}
```

on python3 you don't need OrderedDict because all dicts keep order on python 3

Comment: I got the error : ```sort = dict(sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['conso']))
KeyError: 'conso' ``` (conso is the real name of the key)

With Python 3, which field is used for automatic sorting ? the first ? or is it based on something else ?

Comment: it's not a sorting, it an order (the order of item adding to dict is kept)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6